# Securizar una aplicación hecha con php

Tags: php

Os cuento mi problema, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar porque estoy atascado con el tema

He creado una aplicación web con php para realizar votaciones seguras online que tengo en un GIt y que distribuyo con licencia GNU, se llama [demokratian](http://demokratian.org/votaciones) y empieza a tener cierta reputación como plataforma fiable. La plataforma la están usando bastantes organizaciones, entre ellos partidos políticos para sus votaciones internas, pero me he encontrado que un partido está usando la plataforma, pero parece que ha modificado bastante el software y eso me hace preguntarme, de qué manera se puede securizar el programa ya que pueden haber hecho cualquier tipo de trampa y amparándose en que mi software si es seguro venderlo como que no hay problemas.

Ya sé que php solo se puede ofuscar y tampoco sirve de mucho, así que se me ha ocurrido que la única solución es que al menos las partes más sensibles del programa se puedan de alguna forma “auditar”, que los usuarios puedan ver los cambios que hay comparándolos quizás con el propio git, o con archivos que pueda tener yo en mi servidor y que se viera, como en los git, las líneas modificadas. ¿alguno sabe cómo hacer esto? O mejor ¿alguno tiene alguna idea mejor para securizar la platataforma?

**EDITO**
Edito este post para comentar que he encontrado una posible solución por si le sirve a alguien en algún momento

https://github.com/JBlond/php-diff

Lo que hace este script es precisamente comparar dos archivos.

Si a alguien se le ocurre alguna solución mejor para comprobar que el código en las páginas más "sensibles" no ha sido alterado y que realiza bien el recuento de votos.

Comment: Tu pregunta es demasiado amplia y tal vez *off-topic*. En cuanto a *segurizar* (preferible a *securizar*), creo que debes elegir, tal vez, algún otro tipo de licencia. La licencia GNU GPL v3, (actualmente recomendada) establece los parámetros para el [*copyleft*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Copyleft). En todo caso, parece que el problema que tienes es más de ámbito legal que de programación. Saludos

Comment: Gracias @Mauricio Contreras . El problema es que no quiero dejar de distribuirlo como GNU ( efectivamente v3) ya que creo en el software libre, pero me gustaría que fuera un programa seguro. Me da igual que lo modifiquen, pero si esta modificado los usuarios deberían saber que ha sido así.

Comment: Si una organización o un particular modifica el software para uso privado, no está obligado a publicar la modificaciones, en cambio si lo usa de forma pública, la licencia GPL le obliga a publicar las modificaciones: [GPL - Versiones modificadas](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic). Nuevamente me parece que el terreno es más legal que otra cosa.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque el problema se basa mas en lo legal que de programación.

Comment: Muchas gracias de nuevo @Mauricio Contreras . Siento que opineis que es un tema de licencias, es una parte que tengo controlada y conozco. Tengo clara las limitaciones y lo que permite las distintas licencias, pero lo que yo quiero es que los usuarios que usen la aplicación al votar puedan comprobar que el programa se sigue conservando íntegro en las partes mas comprometidas de forma que si  le hacen cambios, si quieren que le llamen demokratian modificado o lo que sea, pero que los votantes puedan verificar que no les engañan.

Comment: Se me ocurre que separes entonces el código. Planteas: *las partes más sensibles del programa se puedan de alguna forma “auditar”*. La licencia GPL v3 te permite distribuir código libre junto con material con *copyright*, si deseas mantener la parte *sensible* como núcleo inalterable, podrías implementar una licencia de *copyright* exclusiva sobre dicho núcleo, obligando a quien lo altere a informar de los cambios, en caso de que concedas permiso de cambios sobre dicho *nucleo*. No se me ocurre otra cosa. Saludos

Comment: La respuesta no va en la pregunta amigo, para eso tienes abajo la zona de respuestas

Comment: Por otro lado tu pregunta luce amplia y basada en opiniones lo cual generará su cierre